# WordPress uploads do not show up and I see the white screen of death in some cases

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, hosting, web-hosting

Recently I have installed my own-made theme on my WordPress and after that a few problems have occurred.

> Firstly when I upload a photo or file from my site's admin panel it
>   does not show up under Media tab. and when I try to define a thumbnail
>   for a post I cannot see the photos. Therefore I deactivated my
>   own-made theme and changed it to 2017 WordPress theme. after that when
>   I uploaded images they showed up in my Media tab but again when using
>   one of them as a post thumbnail (after reactivating my theme) they showed up like below:

[image: This is how the thumbnail shows on my website]

I've tried several ways to fix this issue such as:

**1) Deactivating my whole plugins.**

**2) Increase PHP Memory Limit by editing the wp-config.php file:**

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

**3) Changing file permissions of my site's uploads folder and etc.**

> Secondly when I activate my own-made theme some times I see the
>   popular **white screen of death**.(For example when I define a new category and press the publish key I get redirected to a white empty page) And I don't know what problem my theme
>   has that makes this happen.

What changes must be done to my own-made theme in order to fix the white screen of death and uploads issues?

Comment: Have you tried using the WordPress debugging feature to see if any error messages are logged? https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Thanks, after trying a lot I turned debugging mode on I found that my functions.php file has a problem as soon as I fixed it both uploads problem and white screen of death issue were disappeared. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot I turned **debugging mode** on I found that my functions.php file has a problem as soon as I fixed it both ***uploads problem*** and ***white screen*** of death issue were disappeared. Thanks a million.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the problem in your functions.php?

Comment: It was really a simple issue. There was an extra space in the beginning of my functions.php file and I think that's because I had edited that file using Notepad++ and with UTF8-BOM Encoding.

Answer (score -1):

nah this looks like a pebkac issue. 1st look in the settings media upload folder. Because this is pebkac most likely you didn't uncheck your date and time image folder. If you did the process is still the same.

FTP in and locate the image upload folder. change the permissions to 777 and press recurse into subdirectories .